# Load R data into different environments using Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am using shiny's fileInput() on the ui.r side to allow a user to read in two different .Rdata files and then subsequently do things on those files.

The problem is that when the user reads in .Rdata file1 it holds a dataframe called "dat" and the second .Rdata also holds a dataframe called "dat". I cannot solve that problem, it will always be true due to a piece of legacy code.

So my goal is to allow the user to load the first .Rdata file and access the df called "dat" and also load the second .Rdata file and also access the df called dat such that they remain as two separate objects throughout the remainder of the user's session.

Now in my server.R program, I read in both file1 and file2 as follows:

```
Rfile1 <- reactive({
    infile <- input$Rfile1
    sessionEnvir <- sys.frame()
    if (!is.null(input$Rfile1)) load(input$Rfile1$datapath, sessionEnvir)
})

Rfile2 <- reactive({
    infile <- input$Rfile2
    sessionEnvir <- sys.frame()
    if (!is.null(input$Rfile2)) load(input$Rfile2$datapath, sessionEnvir)
})  

observeEvent(input$doStuff, {   
    Rfile1 <- get(Rfile1())
    Rfile2 <- get(Rfile2())
    newDat <- merge(Rfile1, Rfile2, by.x = input$mergeKey1, by.y = input$mergeKey2)
... more stuff
    })
```

So what is happening here is that Rfile2 overwrites Rfile1 and they are both the same thing.

My attempt to solve this was to try and load the .Rdata files into different environments such as:

```
Rfile1 <- reactive({
    infile <- input$Rfile1
    e1 <- new.env()
    if (!is.null(input$Rfile1)) load(input$Rfile1$datapath, e1)
})

Rfile2 <- reactive({
    infile <- input$Rfile2
    e2 <- new.env()
    if (!is.null(input$Rfile2)) load(input$Rfile2$datapath, e2)
})  

observeEvent(input$doStuff, {   
    Rfile1 <- get(Rfile1(), envir = e1)
    Rfile2 <- get(Rfile2(), envir = e2)
    newDat <- merge(Rfile1, Rfile2, by.x = input$mergeKey1, by.y = input$mergeKey2)
... more stuff
    })
```

However, this didn't seem to work such that the two files, Rfile1() and Rfile2() remain as separate files as I would hope.

Can anyone point to the mistake I am making such that Rfile1() and Rfile2() remain are accessible as the two separate objects they are intended to be?

Below is code to reproduce the problem I am experiencing. First, create the R files and then using the Shiny app you can read both of them in individually.

If you first read in the file1 using the app and view the structure, it is read in. Then, if you read in file2 and view the structure, it is also read in. But, if you immediately view the structure of file1 again, it appears file2 has taken its place.

I have tried loading and calling the data into separate environments, and wasn't successful. So, either I am doing that incorrectly, or I have a larger misunderstanding.

## First create sample data files

```
dat <- data.frame(ID1 = 1:10, var2 = rnorm(10))
save(dat, file = 'file1.Rdata')
dat <- data.frame(ID2 = 1:10, var2 = rnorm(10))
save(dat, file = 'file2.Rdata')
```

## ui.R

```
library(markdown)
workDir <- getwd()
shinyUI(navbarPage("Toolbar",
tabPanel("Merge Variables",
sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel( 

helpText("Choose the two data files to be merged.
    Each file must curently be formatted as .Rdata file"),

fileInput('Rfile1', 'Read in File 1', accept=c('.RData', '.Rda')),
fileInput('Rfile2', 'Read in File 2', accept=c('.RData', '.Rda')),

actionButton("foo1", "View data structure of F1"),
actionButton("foo2", "View data structure of F2"),

helpText("Choose the variables from each file to use as the merge key"),

uiOutput("mergeKey1"),
uiOutput("mergeKey2"),

textInput("new.data.name", label = "Save new .Rdata as:",
     value = paste(workDir, '/filename.Rdata', sep='')),

actionButton("MergeSave", "Merge and Save New Data")

), # end sidebar
    mainPanel(
    h1('Merge Variables Report'),
    verbatimTextOutput('mergeReport'),
    verbatimTextOutput('foo1'),
    verbatimTextOutput('foo2')
  )
)
  ) # end tabpanel for merge variables
)) # end program
```

## server.R

```
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=100*1024^2) 
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    Rfile1 <- reactive({
        infile <- input$Rfile1
        sessionEnvir <- sys.frame()
        if (!is.null(input$Rfile1)) load(input$Rfile1$datapath, sessionEnvir)
    })

    Rfile2 <- reactive({
        infile <- input$Rfile2
        sessionEnvir <- sys.frame()
        if (!is.null(input$Rfile2)) load(input$Rfile2$datapath, sessionEnvir)
    })  

    output$mergeKey1 <- renderUI({
        df1 <- get(Rfile1())
        if(is.null(df1)) return(NULL)
        nms1 <- names(df1)
        selectInput("mergeKey1","Select Merge Key From the Common Variables", nms1, multiple=FALSE, selectize = FALSE)
    })  

    output$mergeKey2 <- renderUI({
        df2 <- get(Rfile2())
        if(is.null(df2)) return(NULL)
        nms2 <- names(df2)
        selectInput("mergeKey2","Select Merge Key From the Common Variables", nms2, multiple=FALSE, selectize = FALSE)
    })      

    #observeEvent(input$MergeSave, {    
    output$mergeReport <- renderPrint({
        input$MergeSave     
        Rfile1 <- get(Rfile1())
        Rfile2 <- get(Rfile2())
        newDat <- merge(Rfile1, Rfile2, by.x = input$mergeKey1, by.y = input$mergeKey2)
        save(newDat, file = input$new.data.name)
        cat('All done:', '\n')
        })  

    output$foo1 <- renderPrint({
        input$foo1
        isolate({   
        Rfile1 <- get(Rfile1())
        str(Rfile1)
        })   
    })      

    output$foo2 <- renderPrint({
        input$foo2
        isolate({   
        Rfile2 <- get(Rfile2())
        str(Rfile2)
        })   
    })          
}) # end Program
```

Comment: Is there a way you can make this more reproducible? It would be nice to be able to copy/paste code to test different possible solutions. It's not easy to do that with what you have now. Maybe write a code block to create sample Rdata files and read them as static paths rather than uploaded files. I assume that would be sufficient to recreate the problem.

Comment: Could you put the two `data.frame`s each in their own `list` and access them via `list1$dat` and `list2$dat`? Or just rename the first one when it is read in?

Comment: Apologies for not adding the reproducible code at the outset, it is there now I believe sufficiently complete for anyone to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I may have solved my own question. I believe I can do something like e1 <- new.env()
e2 <- new.env() at the very top of the server.r R file and then each time I load or call these dataframes reference the environment to which they are loaded. Curious if that is a good solution from the perspective of others or if an alternative method is suggested.